# Xpath for text between tag with space in between after every tag change

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, normalize-space

text is  like

```
<tag>Head Office41-43 Ricketts Road<tag/> <tag>Mount Waverley, Melbourne<tag/>
```

iam getting result as

```
Head Office41-43 Ricketts RoadMount Waverley, Melbourne
```

but i want it as

```
Head Office41-43 Ricketts Road Mount Waverley, Melbourne
```

code i am using is

```
response.xpath('string(normalize-space(//*/text()[contains(normalize-space(), "{}")]/../..))'.format(marker))
```

where marker is the text.

so instead of `RoadMount` I want `Road Mount`

see the tag wrapped:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKwJ1.png)

this is the code iam using
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zJWP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is returning multiple values - all you have to do is join them with a separator:

```py
xpath = 'string(normalize-space(//*/text()[contains(normalize-space(), "{}")]/../..))'.format(marker))
results = " ".join(response.xpath(xpath).getall())
#                                        ^^^^^^^^
# note: don't forget to use getall to retrieve all results
print(results)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working.

Comment: @TusharDeora What xpath client are you using?

Comment: iam using scrapy 2.5.0. i don't know how to see xpath client. i checked on internet but not getting any info.

Comment: @Grantitosauraus please see my new edit.

Comment: @TusharDeora ah, then you should use `getall()` to retrieve all results of your xpath query. See my edit.